# Screen Rotation after building application

Tags: react-native, expo

First, sorry for my english.

I got a big problem, when I’m using expo start for develop my application, my differents screens are responsive (Especially footer bar, content and header…) but when I build the App using expo build:android or expo build:ios, it’s keeping responsive but I think the App is setting fixed values.

For example, if I rotate the screen from Portrait to Landscape, the footer is going to disappear and I can’t scroll the content like in the “debug” mode.

Changing orientation in debug mode :

[Link to screen](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/30/1/1563779941-screenshot-20190722-085917-expo.jpg)

Changing orientation after build :

[Link to screen](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/30/1/1563779941-screenshot-20190722-085850-application-koust.jpg)

Someone got an idea from where it could come from ? Thanks!

**Edit**

Code of the Home Screen :

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList, Alert, TouchableHighlight, Image } from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Title, Left, Icon, Right, Button, Body, Content, Card, CardItem, Footer, FooterTab, Badge } from "native-base";
var ls = require('react-native-local-storage');

import {handleAndroidBackButton, removeAndroidBackButtonHandler} from '../Services/androidBackButton';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      GridListItems: [
        { key: "Commandes",
          icon: "cart",
          color: "#ff2d55",
          toggleName: "Commandes"},
        { key: "Fiches Techniques",
          icon: "paper",
          color: "#ff9500",
          toggleName: "Recettes"},
        { key: "Inventaire",
          icon: "book",
          color: "#4cd964",
          toggleName: "Inventaires"}
      ],
      userGroupId: null,
      loaded: false,
      badgeCommande: 0
    };
  }

  componentWillMount = async() => {

    await ls.get('userGroupID').then((grpid) => {this.setState({userGroupId: grpid})}).then(async() => {
                                                                 const response = await fetch('https://koustapp.com/apex/rest/mobile/notif_commande?groupid='.concat(this.state.userGroupId));
                                                                 const json = await response.json().then((data) => {
                                                                   ls.save('badgeCommande', data.items[0].value);
                                                                   console.log(data.items[0].value);
                                                                 });
                                                               }).then(async() => {
                                                                  await ls.get('badgeCommande').then((data) => {
                                                                                                      this.setState({loaded: true,
                                                                                                                     badgeCommande: data});
                                                                                                    });
                                                               })

   }

   componentDidMount() {
     handleAndroidBackButton(() => {

       Alert.alert(
          "Retour à la connexion",
          "Êtes vous sûr de vouloir retourner à l'écran de connexion ?",
         [
           {text: 'Non', style: 'cancel'},
           {text: 'Oui', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.goBack()},
         ]
       );
     });
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
    removeAndroidBackButtonHandler();
  }

  render() {
      if (this.state.loaded === 'false') {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Image
              source={require("./../../assets/logo_login.png")}
              style={[
                {
                  resizeMode: "contain",
                  width: 350,
                  height: 162
                }
              ]}
            />
        </View>
        );
      }  else {

        let footerBadgeCommande;

        if(this.state.badgeCommande != 0){

          footerBadgeCommande = <Button badge vertical onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Commandes')}>
            <Badge style={{ backgroundColor: '#ff9500' }}><Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 10 }}>{this.state.badgeCommande}</Text></Badge>
            <Icon name="cart" style={styles.footerIcon}/>
            <Text style={styles.footerText}>Commandes</Text>
          </Button>;
        } else {
          footerBadgeCommande = <Button vertical onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Commandes')}>
            <Icon name="cart" style={styles.footerIcon}/>
            <Text style={styles.footerText}>Commandes</Text>
          </Button>;
        }

        return (
          <Container>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Header style={styles.header}>
              <Left>
                <Button
                  transparent
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
                  <Icon name="menu" style={{color:'white'}}/>
                </Button>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <View>
                  <Button
                    transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Accueil')}>
                    <Image
                      style={{resizeMode: 'contain', height: 35, width: 74, alignSelf: 'center' }}
                      source={require('../../assets/logo_sidebar.png')}
                    />
                  </Button>
                </View>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                <Button
                  transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
                  <Icon name="settings" style={{color:'white'}}/>
                </Button>
              </Right>
            </Header>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    data={ this.state.GridListItems }
                    renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                    <TouchableHighlight
                      underlayColor='white'
                      onPress={() => {

                        try {
                          (item.toggleName);
                          this.props.navigation.navigate(item.toggleName);
                        } catch (error) {
                          ("Error navigate component" + error);
                        }

                      }}
                      >
                      <View style={styles.GridViewContainer}>
                       <Icon name={item.icon} style={[styles.gridIcon, {color: item.color}]}/>
                       <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout}> {item.key} </Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight> }
                    numColumns={1}
                 />
                </View>
              </ScrollView>
              <Footer>
                <FooterTab style={styles.footerContainer}>
                  <Button vertical onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Recettes')}>
                    <Icon name="paper" style={styles.footerIcon}/>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Fiches Techniques</Text>
                  </Button>
                  {footerBadgeCommande}
                  <Button vertical>
                    <Icon name="apps" style={styles.footerIcon}/>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Plus..</Text>
                  </Button>
                </FooterTab>
              </Footer>
            </React.Fragment>
          </Container>
        );
      }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    flex:1
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    marginTop:10
  },
  header:{
    backgroundColor: '#2578cf',
  },
  GridViewContainer: {
   flex:1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   height: 220,
   marginRight:30,
   marginLeft:30,
   margin: 5,
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   borderWidth:1,
   borderColor: "#2578cf"
  },
  GridViewTextLayout: {
   fontSize: 20,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   color: 'black',
   padding: 10,
 },
 footerText: {
   fontSize: 10,
   textAlign: 'center',
   color: 'white'
 },
 footerContainer:{
   backgroundColor: '#2578cf',
 },
 footerIcon: {
   color: 'white',
 },
 gridIcon: {
   color: '#2578cf',
   fontSize: 60
 }
});
```

Comment: Please share the code on the screen.

Comment: Doing it. Thanks.

Comment: Please wrap your view in <Scrollview>,
like, ```<Scrollview style={{flex: 1}}><View>....</View><Scrollview/>```

Comment: Did it, but got the same problem :/